# Flipping a molecule vs. mirror behind compound

Tags: stereochemistry

Why aren't these enantiomers?

If you place a mirror behind the compound and look into the mirror, you get the second drawing.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you place a mirror behind the compound and look into the mirror,
>   you get the second drawing

"If you place a mirror behind compound 1 and look into the mirror" - If by that you mean, generate the mirror image of compound 1, well OK, but that does not produce compound 2. It generates the molecule labeled "mirror image" in the following diagram, and it is a non-superimposable mirror image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How does one get "good" at this?

Comment: Models help a lot, especially in the beginning.

Comment: What about just assigning R/S configurations? Would that always be able to tell me whether I'm looking at enantiomers or diastereomers?

Comment: Yes, that would do it.